# If $f\in L^1(\mu)$ then $f$ is finite $\mu$-a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Prove that if $f,g\in L^1(\mu)$ then $f$ is finite $\mu$-a.e. (almost everywhere).

**My proof**:

Let $A=\{x:f(x)\geqslant n,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

I intend to show $\mu(A)=0$

As $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$

$\int |f|d\mu\leqslant \infty$ then $\exists C$ such that  $\int |f|d\mu<C$

Applying Chebyshev inequality:

$\mu(A)\leqslant\frac{1}{n}\int |f|d\mu<\frac{1}{n}C\implies \mu(A)<\frac{1}{n}C\\\implies\mu(A)<\frac{1}{n}C\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A)<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}C=0\implies \mu(A)=0 $

**Questions:**

Is my proof right? If not why not?
What are the alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be applying Chebyshev to $\{x : f(x) \ge n\}$ (for some fixed $n$), but since $\{x : f(x) \ge n\} \subseteq \{x : f(x) \ge n, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, you're fine

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Wolfy It comes from an exercise set that a Professor handled me.

Comment: I see what book are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice proof—it looks right to me.

> What are the alternatives?

Personally I would write the proof a bit simpler.
Let $A = \{x : f(x) = \infty\}$ (equivalent to your definition, but I'm not using $n$ and then taking a limit!)
Now note that $A$ is a measurable set, so
$$
\int |f| \, d\mu  \ge \int_A |f|\, d\mu = \int_A \infty \, d\mu = \infty \cdot \mu(A).
$$
Recall that in measure theory we define $0 \cdot \infty = 0$. Anyway, since $f$ is $L^1$, this integral should be finite, so we have to have $\mu(A) = 0$.